# MongoDB Como obtener los documentos de una búsqueda profunda?

Tags: base-de-datos, funciones, mongodb

Tengo este codigo:

```
function(añoRegistro,mesRegistro,nombreLugar,codigoBusqueda,arregloTags) {


registros = db.usuarios.find({'puntosRecoleccion.objetosRegistrados.fechaRegistro.año':"2016"
//'puntosRecoleccion.objetosRegistrados.fechaRegistro.año':añoRegistro,'puntosRecoleccion.objetosRegistrados.fechaRegistro.mes':mesRegistro
    },{
    nombre:1,
    'puntosRecoleccion.nombre':1,
    'puntosRecoleccion.telefono':1,
    'puntosRecoleccion.direccion':1,
    'puntosRecoleccion.objetosRegistrados.codigoBusqueda':1,
    'puntosRecoleccion.objetosRegistrados.tags':1,
    'puntosRecoleccion.objetosRegistrados.fechaRegistro.año':1,
    'puntosRecoleccion.objetosRegistrados.fechaRegistro.mes':1
    });
```

estoy intentando que aparezcan solo los objetos registrados cuya año sea 2016 pero cuando lo pruebo, aparecen los todos los registros relacionados a cualquier año

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo